# JBoss jBPM console web application

Tags: jbpm

I have installed **jbpm-4.4**, connected  **jboss-5.0.0.GA** to **JBOSS- JBOSS-CONSOLE WEB APPLICATION** through **MSSQL SERVER 2005** and

for some strange reason I had this message "***createQuery is not valid without active transaction***".

I already searched in the web for the solution but unfortunately I didn´t find something that could help me with this one.

Please if someone knows how to fix this please reply me.

I attached files to help you understanding the error.

Regards

***Chris***

Answer (score 3):

In version 4.4 you can only get HSQL,MySQL,Oracle and PostgreSQL scripts handy but not SQL server script. The script that you were trying to run doesn't comply with SQL Server syntax. I think JBPM is not been tested against the SQL Server